# TypeScript: how to extract type of array item that's nested item itself

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have an object of this interface

```
interface PaginatedResult {
  results: {
   item: Item;
  }[];
  pagination: {
    pageSize: number;
    offset: number;
    total: number;
  }
}
```

How do I get that `Item` type of results `item`?

If I'd wanted just type of results I'd go `PaginatedResult["results"]` but that resolves to `{items: Item}[]`

Answer (score 1):

You can do `PaginatedResult['results'][number]['item']` like so:

```js
type Item = {
  // ...
}

interface PaginatedResult {
  results: {
   item: Item;
  }[];
  pagination: {
    pageSize: number;
    offset: number;
    total: number;
  }
}

type P = PaginatedResult['results'][number]['item']
```

Comment: Ok, cool!
What if `results` look like this?
```
results: {
   item: Item;
  }[] | null | undefined;
```

Comment: I got it with `type P = Exclude<PaginatedResult['results'], null | undefined>[number]['item']`

Answer (score 0):

```js
type Item = {
  ItemId: number,
  ItemName: string
}

interface PaginatedResult {
  results: {
   item: Item;
  }[];
  pagination: {
    pageSize: number;
    offset: number;
    total: number;
  }
}

const o: PaginatedResult = {
  results: [
    { item: {ItemId: 1, ItemName: "Item1"}},
    { item: {ItemId: 2, ItemName: "Item2"}}
  ],
  pagination: {
    pageSize: 2,
    offset: 2,
    total: 69
  }
}

type NewItem = typeof o.results[0]["item"]
// hovering over NewItem shows
// type NewItem = {
//    ItemId: number;
//    ItemName: string;
// }
```